# Separator Lines in Xamarin Forms ListView are only between items on iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin Forms Listview with a GroupHeader:

```
        <ListView x:Name="listView"
                      ios:ListView.SeparatorStyle="FullWidth"
                      AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
                      AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                      IsGroupingEnabled="true"
                      SeparatorVisibility="Default" 
                      IsPullToRefreshEnabled="False"
                      SeparatorColor="Red"
                      SelectionMode="None"
                      Footer=""
                      BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextCell Text="Header Cell"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextCell Text="Item Cell"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

On iOS the separator line (red) is only visible between the items, but not between header and items:
[image: iOS ListView]

On Android the line is also between Header and items: [image: Droid Screenshot]

I only found some suggestions to remove the separator lines on iOS (Setting SeparatorColor transparent).

How can i get the android behavior on iOS?

Comment: Well Headers in iOS don't have separators, if you want them to have separators you will have to remove the default ones and just add your own using BoxView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BoxView to achieve the effect you want, modify your code as follows:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView"
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
    IsGroupingEnabled="True"
    SeparatorVisibility="None"
    SelectionMode="None"
    Footer=""
    BackgroundColor="Transparent">
    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Header Cell" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
                    <BoxView HeightRequest="0.5" Color="Red" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,8,0,0"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Item Cell" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
                    <BoxView HeightRequest="0.5" Color="Red" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I accept this as an answer. Setting ListView ios:ListView.GroupHeaderStyle="Grouped" works also in my case. Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/listview-group-header-style